# Responsive design on iPhone 6?

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design

I am having trouble with my responsive design on my iPhone 6. On the desktop, the css works, media query seems like its correct, but when I put it onto the server and actually test it on my phone, its as if nothing happened.

I've already used the meta tag and that helped it go into phone layout, but the text, img and button are all out of place.

My CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 308px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .jumbotron h2 {
    bottom: 3em;
  }
  .jumbotron img {
    bottom: -5em;
  }
  .jumbotron button {
    bottom: -1em;
  }
}
```

Comment: In `head` section you assigned `viewport` code ?? try  `@media screen and (max-width: 308px) and (orientation: portrait)`

Comment: yes i did <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: try `@media screen and (max-width: 308px) and (orientation: portrait)` remove `only`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
max-width: 308px
```

is too small

you can follow bootstrap size on phone
Phones (<768px)
so that you should change to

```
max-width:768px;
```

Comment: According to chrome, it's 375 instead. 768's the size of an iPad.

Comment: anyway, <768 is for mobile version including Ipad